# Add numbers in Array using recursion and disregarding any other data type

Tags: javascript, recursion

Forgive me if this is to basic or have been asked already, but I'm stuck at this problem and I feel like it must be something simple I'm not seeing.

I want to add all numbers in the array using recursion(done!) and I'm missing a statement to ignore all other types of values. 
For example:

```
var arr = [1,'a','b',2,[1],'c']
sumValues(arr) // => 4 . 

function sumValues(arr){
  if(arr.length === 0){
    return 0;
  } // if the array is empty
  if(arr.length > 0){
    if(Array.isArray(arr[0])){
      return sumValues(arr[0]);
    } // if the next element is an array
    return arr.shift() + sumValues(arr);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your recursive call for nested arrays uses `arraySum` instead of `sumValues`.

Comment: So then you're asking how to differentiate between a string and a number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Number.isFinite(value)` to determine whether a variable is a number other than `NaN` or `Infinity`.

Based on this test, check and conditionally add values to the summation.

```js
function sumValues(arr){
 if (arr.length === 0){
  return 0;
 } // if the array is empty
 if (arr.length > 0) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr[0])){
   return sumValues(arr[0]);
  } // if the next element is an array

  // pop the first element off the array
  var value = arr.shift();
  // check its type and conditionally add it to the summation
  return (Number.isFinite(value) ? value : 0) + sumValues(arr);
 }
}

var arr = [1,'a','b',2,[1],'c']
console.log(sumValues(arr)); // 4

arr = [1,'3','b',2,[1,[4,3]],'c'];
console.log(sumValues(arr)); // 11 (because '3' is ignored)
```

Comment: This doesn't account for `NaN`. Use `Number(value) === value` to check if it is a Number instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: it breaks on string numbers. `[1,'3','b',2,[1,[4,3]],'c'];`

Comment: Should `'3'` be considered a number?  My take is no, but only the OP can answer for sure.  I've updated my answer slightly.

Comment: @Tschallacka: *"I want to add all numbers in the array... and I'm missing a statement to ignore all other types of values"* Strings and numbers are distinct types.

Comment: Depends of the interpretation and or datasource. If values come from json they might be encoded as strings when parsed by the javascript. @OP would need to comment on the issue if he considers numeric string input also a number that needs to be added.

Comment: `NaN` is a number, as are `Infinity` and `-Infinity`. I don't know why they should be excluded, though one could end early if `NaN` is encountered.

Comment: ...however, if you did exclude infinite numbers and `NaN`, you could simply use `Number.isFinite()` instead, which will return `false` for any input that is not a `number` type or that is `NaN` or infinite... `return (Number.isFinite(value) ? value : 0) + sumValues(arr);`

Comment: ...also, the `.length > 0` check isn't needed, since it'll never be less than `0`.

Comment: All good suggestions :)  I switched to `Number.isFinite` but left things like that since the question was really about determining whether a value was a number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isNaN()` to test if something is Not a Number.
By using the boolean inversion operator `!` you can test if it's a number:
`!isNaN(variable)`

Basically it says: if variable is Not Not A Number
A double negative is a positive, so it becomes: if variable Is a Number

```js
function sumValues(arr){
  if(Array.isArray(arr)) {
     if(arr.length > 0) {
       // Get the first value and remove it from the array.
       var first = arr.shift();
       
       // Test if it's numeric.
       if(!isNaN(first)) {
          // If it is, parse the value, add the rest resulting array values.
          return parseInt(first) + parseInt(sumValues(arr));
       }
       // if the first item is an array, we need to iterate that one too.
       if(Array.isArray(first)) {
          return parseInt(sumValues(first)) + parseInt(sumValues(arr));
       }
       // It isn't a number, just continue with what's left of the array.
       return parseInt(sumValues(arr));
     }
     // The array is empty, return 0.
     return 0;
  }
  // It isn't an array
  else {
    // Is it an number?
    if(!isNaN(arr)) {
       // return the number
       return parseInt(arr);
    }
    // return 0, it's a dead end.
    return 0;
  }
}
var arr = [1,'a','b',2,[1],'c'];
console.log(sumValues(arr)) // => 4 .

arr = [1,'3','b',2,[1,[4,3]],'c'];
console.log(sumValues(arr)) // => 14 .

arr = 'foobar';
console.log(sumValues(arr)) // => 0 .

arr = '10';
console.log(sumValues(arr)) // => 10 .

arr = ['foobar',10,'20',[10,20,'foobar']];
console.log(sumValues(arr)) // => 60 .
```

Answer (score 0):

You're squashing an array, there is no need to create your own reduction function. Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to squash the array. Upon each iteration, check if the current element is a number; if it is, add it to the accumulator; if not, move on.

To make it recursive (as shown in the example below) check if the current element is an array; if it is, add the result of calling the function on the element to the accumulator.

```js
const input = [1,'a','b',2,[1],'c'];

const sumValues = i => 
  i.reduce((m, e) => m + (e instanceof Array ? sumValues(e) : (isNaN(e) ? 0 : e)), 0);

console.log(sumValues(input));
```